# Slow sqlite performance on dozens of tiny queries

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite

My **Andl** project optionally uses SQLite as the backend, and I have hundreds of unit tests to run against the database. A typical set of mixed queries (including updates) runs in 800ms baseline, and nearly 5s with SQLite, or about 6x slower. That's a real problem as the number of tests increases.

Performance testing (VS) shows the SQLite overhead is about 22% CPU usage (ticks). Measured CPU usage is negligible (under 5%), but disk usage maxes out at near 100%. The system appears to be disk bound.

So how do I configure SQLite to execute lots of small queries really fast? Each test is at least one transaction (for isolation), but I have no need for robustness against data loss. I just need the final database to be on disk.

- System: Windows 10, i7, 16Gb memory, 512 Gb SSD.
- Code: C# with Interop to sqlite3.dll, no other libraries involved.
- Project: https://github.com/david-pfx/Andl.

---

Update: SQLite `pragma synchronous=OFF` reduces the query overhead a lot. Baseline for the relevant test suite is 5 secs; with this option the SQL tests now run in 11 secs (instead of minutes). This is now acceptable.

Looks like this is the answer, unless something better turns up.

Comment: You might want to show us these queries, and optimizing the underlying SQL might yield the greatest performance gains.

Comment: Need table schemas, indexes on those tables, queries, [execution plans](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), are you batching multiple updates together in transactions, journal and synchronous mode pragma settings, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: /edit: by this project i see, it make sense to test with real sql ;)

You could also use different sqlite in memory dbs, maybe it is faster than the transactions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the queries are generated and basically one of everything, not much room to optimise

Comment: @shawn: the schemas are generated and very simple, maybe 1 to 5 columns, and each test is a transaction boundary so not easy to batch.

Comment: @David: yes, but using in-memory means nothing on disk at the end and I need that to cross-check the tests worked correctly.